# fine uploader direct to s3 pausing on large uploads, pause + restart fixes it

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader

Using FineUploader in S3 mode we're seeing uploads just pause periodically.  clicking the pause and restart will allow the upload to finish.  i'd be glad to post relevant snippets of the implementation if it'd help, but its pretty much stock.  we're uploading large PDF files with scanned page images.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most definitely a network issue between your client and S3 (or your signature server).  In some cases, if there is a connection issue, the upload won't fail until the browser times out the request.  The default browser timeout is a large value.  Pausing actually aborts the request, and "continue" re-creates it and starts with the chunk after the last successful one.

This was discussed in [#743](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/743) in the issue tracker, and we ultimately decided not to allow custom timeouts to be specified due to some reasons detailed in the issue.